# VBA Autofilter - disable cells if multiple conditions are met

Tags: vba, excel

This autofilter filters cells so field 6 through 8 contain "yes":

```
With Range("F6:H500")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="yes"
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="yes"
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="yes"
End With
```

How can I achieve the opposite? I would like to have every combination, but NOT if every cell contains "yes". So "yes", "yes", blank.. or "yes", blank, blank

thanks.

**update**
tried this, but failed:

```
For Each r In rng.Rows
    If rng.Cells(r.Row, 1).Text Like "yes" Then
        r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: I think the way I would do it would be to add a helper column with a formula that adds 1 if not all cells are 'yes' and then filter the 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

With ws
    For i = 6 To 500
        If .Cells(i, 6) Like "yes" And .Cells(i, 7) Like "yes" And .Cells(i, 8) Like "yes" Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

And unhide with:

```
Sub ShowAllRows()
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: you are awesome :) one small problem - this seems to interfere with the autofilters (from the other question)...

Comment: What do you mean with that exactly?

Comment: Well first I apply the autofilters from the previous question. After that I would like to apply this additional filter. The results are not as expected, but don't know where it went wrong...:-/

Comment: It probably should be `For i = 7 to 500` so it does not hide the filters.

Comment: Thanks - I only compared the row numbering to an existing sheet, which didn't Loop through every element, so the numbering was off... still a beginner in vba :)