# VBA Excel - combine multiple autofilters

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple filters (Range("A5:I5")) and would like to combine those filters consecutively like so:

```
Range("A5:I5").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Range("A6:A500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
Range("B6:B500").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("F6:F500").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="yes", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
Range("G6:G500").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="yes", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
```

However they seem to cancel each other out, my goal is that the "yes" filter only filters on the already filtered data from before.
How can I "stack" filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it to one `Range` like:

```
Range("A5:I5").Autofilter
With Range("A6:I500")
  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
  .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
  .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="yes", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
  .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="yes", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
End With
```

Also try to avoid `.Select`, its not necessary for any operation.

Comment: Awesome this works (will accept in a few mins). Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608486/vba-autofilter-disable-cells-if-multiple-conditions-are-met ? I can't figure out how to add a final condition/criteria